# git command for showing user.name not giving any result

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, git-bash

I am using following git command to get user name but it gives nothing at all.

```
git config user.name
```

Then I tried

```
git config --list
```

That gives everything else but no username and user email details.
Any ideas what is going wrong here or which command should be used instead.
I have tried these command on Git bash for windows 10 and also tried on Command line interface of windows 10. No success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it isn't set already, try running `git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

You should then see it in `git config --list`

[Github: Setting Your Username in Git](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/setting-your-username-in-git)

Comment: thanks c_sagan it was not set after using your command problem resolved.

Comment: Will this not reset the username (if it's already been set) and potentially cause clashes when pushing to github?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you mentioned that you weren't seeing an email set either, along with a missing username. I see answers for setting your username already posted here, but you also want to set your email using `user.email`. 
So you want to run these two commands:

```
git config --global user.name "Your name"
git config --global user.email youremail@email.com
```

After you set this information, it will be set globally and baked into your future commits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check the directory you're in and whether you set the username globally or only for a single repo.

Try 
`$ git config --global user.name`
from your home directory.
Else try 
`$ git config user.name` after changing to the specific directory if the username is not global.